# Get a notification & dialog when the screen is locked

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-alertdialog

In my app when some connections happen, the user should make some decisions. I want the user to do it within a dialog. so if the screen is unlocked show the dialog instantly and if the screen is locked turn on the screen and show the notification (like SMS notifications)and when the user touches the notification and unlocks the screen see the dialog.

Comment: **when some connections happen, the user should make some decisions**   -what does it mean? and Do u want to show alert even if your app is killed?

Comment: @Joe yes, my app has a service waiting for a connection. when the connection has established the user should be notified and and should make some decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [wake lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) which allows you to turn the screen on and keep it on for some time you need.

[Here is the example.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock(int,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: thank you. your answer helped. I didn't need to use broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Broadcast receiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

From the Reciever you will know when screen is on or off:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
        {
            screenon = false;
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
        {
            screenon = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Don't forget to declare receiver in the manifest. 
Showing notification and dialog shouldn't be the problem.
Use android docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just send your notification normally and add the following flags to the activity that is called from the notification.

**YourNotificationService.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**YourActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    getWindow().addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
    );

    ...
}
```